# Using MAX in a SELECT statement with logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max

In a nutshell, I need to get the latest revision of a part. The criteria for determining the latest revision is;

- If all the parts have an alpha revision, then the latest revision based upon the MAX alphabet
- If all the parts have a numeric revision, then the latest revision based upon the MAX numeric
- If some of the parts have letter and some have numbers and letters, then the latest revision would be the MAX alphabet
- If some of the parts have letters, others have numbers, then the latest would the based upon the MAX of the numbers, ignoring the letters

This might seems a bit hazy but should hopefully be clearer with the code below.

```
DECLARE @PARTS TABLE
(
    PART nvarchar(100),
    PART_GENERIC nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('B4294A', 'B4294')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('B4294B', 'B4294')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('B4294C', 'B4294')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('B4323001', 'B4323')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('B4323002', 'B4323')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('B4323003', 'B4323')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('N9648400A', 'N96484')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('N96484A', 'N96484')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('A11089100', 'A11089')
INSERT INTO @PARTS (PART, PART_GENERIC) VALUES ('A11089A', 'A11089')

SELECT PART_GENERIC, MAX(PART) FROM @PARTS GROUP BY PART_GENERIC
```

In the case of rules 1 and 2 above, using the MAX function will get the desired results. The tricky part is the other 2 rules.

The parts are grouped by their generic value above, so I'm looking for the latest revision of each generic part.

I've managed to do this already but it was in a user defined function and is horrendously slow when used in a SELECT statement. I'd therefore like to handle this logic and output a table containing the generic value and the latest revision of the part.

The SELECT statement above will output;

```
A11089 A11089A

B4294  B4294C

B4323  B4323003

N96484 N96484A
```

when I need it to output;

```
A11089 **A11089100**

B4294  B4294C

B4323  B4323003

N96484 N96484A
```

One final point, if the revision is numeric, it's the last 3 characters of the part (e.g. 003, I know that's not strictly speaking a number). If it's a letter, its typically just the last character, e.g. A

Comment: There's really not going to be a fast way to do this.  You basically have multiple pieces of data in the same field and you need to parse them out.  SQL is not optimized for this kind of operation.

Comment: Your rules aren’t clear about parts like N9648400A, that have letters and numbers. Which rule(s) apply if the are parts N9648400A, N9648402E, N96484005, and N96484F, and why? Also, be aware that if you can have a part number like N9648401E2, ISNUMERIC('01E2') = 1. Better to store the revision suffix separately from the part number and also keep track of the revision type (alpha, digits, mixed). Or store the '00' and 'A' parts of revision 00A separately, if the parts are meaningful alone.

Finally, are you certain 'B4323001' cannot be a generic part number as opposed to a revision of 'B4323'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this--it's about the fastest I can make it work:

```
select
    part_generic,
    isnull(
        max(case when minorRevisionNumeric = 1 then part else null end),
        max(case when minorRevisionNumeric = 0 then part else null end)
    ) as revision
from
    (select
        part,
        part_generic,
        isnumeric(replace(part, part_generic, '')) as minorRevisionNumeric
    from
        @parts
    ) y
group by
    part_generic
```

I put the `isnumeric` and `replace` so you're only doing it once per row, and then use that in the calc for the revision number. It works with the sample data you've provided, but if it's not exactly the right logic for what you're looking for, we can always tweak from there.

For posterity, this syntax will only work on SQL Server.

Comment: He can get issues with this though since ISNUMERIC is a little loose.  Maybe do a `PATINDEX('%[a-z]%')` instead?

Comment: @JNK - How is `isnumeric` loose?

Comment: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1e1'), ISNUMERIC('$44'), ISNUMERIC('1.5e34')`

Comment: @JNK - Well, it's defined behavior. `e` is an exponent, and `$44` is a monetary expression. Those are all numeric types that you can insert into SQL Server (in that format). I guess the only other way would be to do a `isnumeric(left(replace(...),1))` to just get one character. I don't know how generic of a solution that would be for this case, though.

Comment: I realize it's defined, but it's not what most users would expect, and it will cause issues if you take for granted that `ISNUMERIC` will return false if there are non-numeric characters.   that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm aware of the "looseness" of the ISNUMERIC function and in this instance, it's safe to use.

Comment: Can you double checked it did work for you as when I run it, the A11089 part is still outputting A11089A as the latest revision when it should be A11089100? Thanks

Comment: OK, figured it out. The part and part_generic are the wrong way around in the ISNUMERIC function. Thanks again.

Comment: Eric has the REPLACE expression backwards. The query should contain REPLACE(PART, PART_GENERIC, ''), not REPLACE(PART_GENERIC, PART, '').

Comment: @sparkymark75 - Sorry, had different column names when I was testing it out, and just did a dumb replace on it. Fixed the answer--thanks!

Comment: Annoyingly, I've just found a scenario where the above doesn't work. If there are 2 parts; M479700H and M4797H, the 00H revision should be the latest but it's not.